# I am bulky although my diet is healthy(at least i think it is healthy)

Tags: diet, body-fat, fat, bellyfat

I am 30 and my height is 5'5. I try to eat healthy and I have following meal-schedule

**Breakfast:**

At 8am on working days

At 11am on weekend

consists of coffee and boiled egg.

**Lunch:**

At 2/3pm on working days

At 4pm on weekend

most of the days it is fruits, sometime eat out.

**Dinner:**

At 8pm on working days

At 10pm on weekend

consists of one tortilla(sometime rice), chicken/beef with some vegetable, dessert(not daily).

*I walk 3 days a week for 1 hour each day.*

*Don't drink soda.*

but my belly is becoming larger day by day. I don't know what I am doing wrong or what I am not doing right.
Although other parts of body are not fat but because of belly/waist-Circumference I look so bulky.

Please suggest what should I do to get a flatter tummy.

Comment: only fruits for lunch?

Comment: mostly yes, but sometimes add some protien beef/chicken but it is very rare.

Comment: To me it seems you are not eating enough ... your breakfast should be your main target. I'd look for something more balanced than a boiled egg...

Furthermore, you're eating way too late for your dinner and probably slowly digesting while you sleep. You seem to wake up later during the weekend, are you an avid beer drinker like myself? If so, try to wake up early anyway and eat something. Then snack at the usual time you'd have breakfast. Then eat lunch at 1pm maximum. Then dinner at 5pm, with a snack in between lunch and dinner.

Comment: calories in vs calores out, you should track your calorie intake as @Daniel mentioned in his answers there a plenty of calories calculator on the internet

Answer (score 3):

Use a calorie expenditure calculator [like this one](http://www.mayoclinic.org/calorie-calculator/itt-20084939) to find your target estimate for intake.  Count your calories and hit that estimate every day.  After one or two weeks, if your weight has not decreased, reduce your caloric intake by 100-500 calories per day.

If you eat more calories than you burn, you get fatter.  It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are huge gaps between meals. Divide your large meals into 5-6 smaller meals. I am no expert but that helped me. May be you can start doing some little exercises - planks, crunches, situps. Include some 10 mins in a day for these exercises. This is my humble opinion. Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that too, i divided my meal in 5 small meals but that made me even more hungry, though I controlled and stuck with 5 meals and didn't take anything in between but it made no difference.

Comment: "Grazing not gorging" is a diet myth

Comment: @HappyDev what were you eating in those 5 meals? They should be 300 calorie meals atleast with proper protein and carb distribution. Just fruits for lunch may not be enough. Add enough bread and protein. Control the portions.

Comment: @Daniel it may be a myth, but worked for me! So might as well work for some odd people like me :)

Comment: @Nerdyme I ate boiled egg and coffee, then milk and cookies, then fruits, then nuts and green tea, then a tortilla and Beef/chicken.

Comment: @Nerdyme Sure thing.  I didn't downvote you, I just figured I'd chime in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I eat more at lunch than you eat during the whole day. If you are still getting fat on this diet, then you should first do a medical check up to rule out problems like e.g. thyroid problems. Absent any medical problems, you should start to exercise a lot more and then later actually increase your food intake. You won't get fat if you training regime drives you toward greater fitness.